# dotnetbrowser with earth plugin too slow

Tags: google-chrome, 3d, dotnetbrowser

i am testing dotnetbrowser from teamdev.com within an wpf application.

when i call google maps 3d functionality like this:

https://www.google.com/maps/@50.052475,8.7434217,109a,20y,41.07h,76.14t/data=!3m1!1e3

the viewer works but is very slow. takes 5x the time as in google chrome on the same machine.

the code is the same as in simple example on teamdev homepage.

any tipps?
gl
teenriot

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Heavyweight browser mode:

```
Browser browser = BrowserFactory.Create(BrowserType.HEAVYWEIGHT);
```

If the problem persists, please contact our support via email address, provided to you in the evaluation email.